# Problem installing mesa-git from unofficial repo (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, mesa

I'm trying to install mesa-git from the unofficial repo in Arch but the install fails. I  would just like to know if there is any way around this or is this method just broken? I did find a video talking about this repo from three years ago and some comments from just 3 weeks ago suggest it worked for them. [The Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KCU1DV6c9E&t=510s).

```
[tanner@Desktop ~]$ sudo pacman -S mesagit
:: There are 24 members in group mesagit:

:: Repository mesa-git



1) clang-git  2) compiler-rt-git  3) lib32-libdrm-git  4) lib32-llvm-git  5) lib32-llvm-libs-git  6) lib32-mesa-git  7) lib32-vulkan-intel-git
   8) lib32-vulkan-mesa-layer-git  9) lib32-vulkan-mesa-layers-git  10) lib32-vulkan-radeon-git  11) libclc-git  12) libdrm-git  13) lldb-git  14) llvm-git
   15) llvm-libs-git  16) llvm-ocaml-git  17) mesa-git  18) opencl-mesa-git  19) vulkan-intel-git  20) vulkan-mesa-git  21) vulkan-mesa-layer-git
   22) vulkan-mesa-layers-git  23) vulkan-radeon-git  24) vulkan-swrast-git

Enter a selection (default=all): 1-6 9-18 20 22 23
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: llvm-git and llvm are in conflict. Remove llvm? [y/N] y
:: lib32-libdrm-git and lib32-libdrm are in conflict. Remove lib32-libdrm? [y/N] y
:: libdrm-git and libdrm are in conflict. Remove libdrm? [y/N] y
:: lib32-llvm-git and lib32-llvm are in conflict. Remove lib32-llvm? [y/N] y
:: lib32-mesa-git and lib32-mesa are in conflict. Remove lib32-mesa? [y/N] y
:: mesa-git and mesa are in conflict. Remove mesa? [y/N] y
:: lib32-vulkan-radeon-git and lib32-vulkan-radeon are in conflict. Remove lib32-vulkan-radeon? [y/N] y
:: vulkan-radeon-git and vulkan-radeon are in conflict. Remove vulkan-radeon? [y/N] y
:: libclc-git and libclc are in conflict. Remove libclc? [y/N] y

Packages (31) lib32-libdrm-2.4.103-1 [removal]  lib32-llvm-11.0.0-2 [removal]  lib32-mesa-20.3.2-1 [removal]  lib32-vulkan-radeon-20.3.2-1 [removal]
              libclc-11.0.0-1 [removal]  libdrm-2.4.103-2 [removal]  llvm-11.0.0-4 [removal]  mesa-20.3.2-2 [removal]  ocaml-4.11.1-1
              ocaml-ctypes-0.17.1-4  ocaml-integers-0.4.0-3  vulkan-radeon-20.3.2-2 [removal]  clang-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1
              compiler-rt-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1  lib32-libdrm-git-2.4.103.r10.gd034db14-1  lib32-llvm-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1
              lib32-llvm-libs-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1  lib32-mesa-git-1:21.0.0_devel.133039.471fd78e3c5-1
              lib32-vulkan-mesa-layers-git-1:21.0.0_devel.133039.471fd78e3c5-1  lib32-vulkan-radeon-git-1:21.0.0_devel.133039.471fd78e3c5-1
              libclc-git-1:12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1  libdrm-git-2.4.103.r10.gd034db14-1  lldb-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1
              llvm-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1  llvm-libs-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1  llvm-ocaml-git-12.0.0_r376022.5c951623bc89-1
              mesa-git-1:21.0.0_devel.133039.471fd78e3c5-1  opencl-mesa-git-1:21.0.0_devel.133039.471fd78e3c5-1
              vulkan-mesa-git-1:21.0.0_devel.132340.296316b5dec-1  vulkan-mesa-layers-git-1:21.0.0_devel.133039.471fd78e3c5-1
              vulkan-radeon-git-1:21.0.0_devel.133039.471fd78e3c5-1

Total Download Size:      1.25 MiB
Total Installed Size:  2045.37 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      1326.37 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'vulkan-mesa-git-1:21.0.0_devel.132340.296316b5dec-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from pkgbuild.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (failed to retrieve some files)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
[tanner@Desktop ~]$

tanner@Desktop 
                   ./sssso-                -------------- 
                 `:osssssss+-              OS: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64 
               `:+sssssssssso/.            Kernel: 5.10.4-arch2-1 
             `-/ossssssssssssso/.          Uptime: 2 days, 27 mins 
           `-/+sssssssssssssssso+:`        Packages: 1124 (pacman) 
         `-:/+sssssssssssssssssso+/.       Shell: bash 5.1.4 
       `.://osssssssssssssssssssso++-      Resolution: 2560x1440 
      .://+ssssssssssssssssssssssso++:     DE: Plasma 5.20.5 
    .:///ossssssssssssssssssssssssso++:    WM: KWin 
  `:////ssssssssssssssssssssssssssso+++.   Theme: Breeze [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
`-////+ssssssssssssssssssssssssssso++++-   Icons: breeze [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3] 
 `..-+oosssssssssssssssssssssssso+++++/`   Terminal: konsole 
   ./++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++/:.     CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (12) @ 3.600GHz 
  `:::::::::::::::::::::::::------``       GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT 
                                           Memory: 7032MiB / 15973MiB
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind linking to the video so that contributors can better understand the context in which the claims of that tutorial are made?

Comment: “The requested URL returned error: 404”: It looks like your unofficial package is outdated. Why not install [mesa-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mesa-git/) from the AUR?

Comment: @Devon I was going to do it from the unofficial repo because it contained everything i needed. All thoes other packages like llvm-git and vulkan-radeon-git ill have to get and build from the AUR as well right?

Comment: Yes, the AUR dependencies not present in official repos will need to be build. However, with the help of a good aur helper (e.g. yay, paru) it shouldn't be that much of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Note this error:

```
error: failed retrieving file 'vulkan-mesa-git-1:21.0.0_devel.132340.296316b5dec-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst'
  from pkgbuild.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
```

It usually means that your local knowledge of pacman repositories is outdated. Try using `pacman -Syu package` instead of `pacman -S package` and it should help with this error.

Note for the sake of completeness - you could also do `pacman -Sy` instead of `pacman -Syu`, but [this is not recommended due to the possibility of introducing inconsistencies in your locally installed dependencies](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5111je/pacman_sy_vs_syu/d78qkyi/).

Comment: Using Syu just skipped mesa-git, said it was already up to date and got the 404 again when trying to download vulkan-mesa-git.

Comment: Sorry then, it seems like the `pkgbuild.com` repos are not up-to-date relative to official AUR repos. You'll need to either wait for them to update or build it yourself from AUR.